# Sed to replace/merge line in etc/group

Tags: sed

I have a list of users from 1 command -

```
getent group ldap-group|cut -c 32-700
```

This gives me a list of users in the form

```
user1,user2,user3...
```

I would like to insert this into /etc/group under sshd

```
sshd:x:74:adminuser,root
```

And I'd like to keep all the text up until root.

I have tried this sed command but it does not actually modify the file correctly.

```
sudo sed -i "s/^(sshd:x:\\d+:root,).*/\\$1(getent group ldap-group|cut -c 32-700)/" /etc/group
```

Can anyone help me with the sed syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try and do it as a one liner

```
groupappend=$(getent group ldap-group|cut -c 32-700)
sed -n "/^sshd:/s/$/,$groupappend/p" /etc/group
```

and if this works for you then

```
sed -i "/^sshd:/s/$/,$groupappend/" /etc/group
```

---

It wasn't clear that you would be running this multiple times, try

```
sed -i "/^sshd/c\sshd:x:74:adminuser,root,$groupappend" /etc/group
```

instead.

Comment: OK that sort of works but I would like to run the command every hour via cron and that will append multiple sshd lines to /etc/group?

Comment: @BryanCochrane: Nope.

Comment: When I ran the last command I ended up with a new identical sshd line added each time.

Comment: @BryanCochrane: I only get one sshd:... line on my CentOS system.